# difference between ipdb and pdb++?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, ipdb

Python has its default debugger called pdb, but there are a few alternatives created by the community. Two of them are [ipdb](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb) and [pdb++](https://github.com/pdbpp/pdbpp). They seem to cater to the same audience, they can both be run directly at the CLI and provide some niceties such as colored output and tab-completion.

Do they serve different purposes or are they simply competing debuggers with similar features?
I'm having trouble understanding when one would wish to use one over the other. There seem to even be people [using both at the same time](https://serebrov.github.io/html/2018-11-28-python-debugging-with-ipdb-pdbpp.html)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65816273/enter-sticky-mode-by-default-with-ipdb

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a `pdbpp` expert, but to me `ipdb` comes with more features (IPython has many "magic" functions such as %timeit, %debug, etc that are handy), while `pdbpp` has a `sticky` mode that displays the source in the terminal as you step through (like GDB's TUI mode) and is more capable than the default `pdb`.

So they are both good options to debug, but my personal preference goes to `ipdb` because I'm used to work interactively from IPython.  I've found I could set my main debugger to `ipdb` like so:

```
export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.set_trace   # or ipdb.sset_trace
```

And put `breakpoint()` in the Python source to debug. If `pdbpp` is also installed, I can invoke `sticky` from the `ipdb` session, which is neat.

Comment: What about alternatives such as sentry and debugpy?